# type safe state handling in functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state

So I want to have a bunch of functions that receive a state and return a result with a new state. In essence, the state monad, but without the monadic methods. Unlike the state monad, the state is not supposed to flow between the functions, rather, a function is called, returns a result and state and the state is saved until the next time the function is called.  So I have a List of functions and a list of states (each function has a different state type) and I want to call each function with its state and update the list of states.

My problem is that I can't make it work without casting.

Here's a REPL session:

```
scala> type StateM[T] = T => (Int, T)
defined type alias StateM

scala> val c: StateM[Int] = {i => (i, i + 1)}
c: (Int) => (Int, Int) = <function1>

scala> val a: StateM[_] = c
a: StateM[_] = <function1>

scala> val z: Any = 0
z: Any = 0

scala> a(z)
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : z.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: _$1 where type _$1
       a(z)
         ^
```

UPDATE: I thought that maybe existential types would help. Something like:

```
scala> type StateT = Pair[StateM[X], X] forSome {type X}
defined type alias StateT

scala> val t: StateT = (c, 0)
t: StateT = (<function1>,0)

scala> t._1(t._2)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : t._2.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: X where type X
       t._1(t._2)
              ^
```

Comment: I'm confused why you would expect `a(z)` to work, which is equivalent to `c(0: Any)`, which is clearly invalid - you can't pass an `Any` to a function that takes an `Int`. Could you explain what you were hoping would happen here?

Comment: I was hoping that I could keep functions that use different states in one map. The T in the function is the type of the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found is to use a class that wraps the two:

```
scala> case class StateWithVal[T](f: StateM[T], v: T) {def apply() = StateWithVal(f, f(v)._2)}
defined class StateWithVal

scala> val sv:StateWithVal[_] = StateWithVal(c, 0)
sv: StateWithVal[_] = StateWithVal(<function1>,0)

scala> sv()
res15: StateWithVal[_] = StateWithVal(<function1>,1)
```